# How to assing values to a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, key-value-store

I am creating a function which is supposed to return a dictionary with keys and values from different lists. But I amhavin problems in getting the mean of a list o numbers as values of the dictionary. However, I think I am getting the keys properly.
This is what I get so far:

```
 def exp (magnitudes,measures):
   """return for each magnitude the associated mean of numbers from a list"""
dict_expe = {}
for mag in magnitudes:
    dict_expe[mag] = 0
    for mea in measures:
        summ = 0
    for n in mea:
        summ += n
        dict_expe[mag] = summ/len(mea)


        return dict_expe

print(exp(['mag1', 'mag2', 'mag3'], [[1,2,3],[3,4],[5]]))
```

The output should be:

```
{mag1 : 2, mag2: 3.5, mag3: 5}
```

But what I am getting is always 5 as values of all keys. I thought about the zip() method but im trying to avoid it as because the it requieres the same length in both lists.

Answer (score 0):

An average of a sequence is `sum(sequence) / len(sequence)`, so you need to iterate through both `magnitudes` and `measures`, calculate these means (arithmetical averages) and store it in a dictionary.

There are much more pythonic ways you can achieve this. All of these examples produce `{'mag1': 2.0, 'mag2': 3.5, 'mag3': 5.0}` as result.

Using `for i in range()` loop:

```
def exp(magnitudes, measures):
    means = {}
    for i in range(len(magnitudes)):
        means[magnitudes[i]] = sum(measures[i]) / len(measures[i])
    return means

print(exp(['mag1', 'mag2', 'mag3'], [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4], [5]]))
```

But if you need both indices and values of a list you can use `for i, val in enumerate(sequence)` approach which is much more suitable in this case:

```
def exp(magnitudes, measures):
    means = {}
    for i, mag in enumerate(magnitudes):
        means[mag] = sum(measures[i]) / len(measures[i])
    return means

print(exp(['mag1', 'mag2', 'mag3'], [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4], [5]]))
```

Another problem hides here: `i` index belongs to `magnitudes` but we are also getting values from `measures` using it, this is not a big deal in your case if you have `magnitudes` and `measures` the same length but if `magnitudes` will be larger you will get an `IndexError`. So it seems to me like using `zip` function is what would be the best choice here (actually as of python3.6 it doesn't require two lists to be the same length, it will just use the length of shortest one as the length of result):

```
def exp(magnitudes, measures):
    means = {}
    for mag, mes in zip(magnitudes, measures):
        means[mag] = sum(mes) / len(mes)
    return means

print(exp(['mag1', 'mag2', 'mag3'], [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4], [5]]))
```

So feel free to use the example which suits your requirements of which one you like and don't forget to add docstring.

More likely you don't need *such pythonic* way but it can be even shorter when **dictionary comprehension** comes into play:

```
def exp(magnitudes, measures):
    return {mag: sum(mes) / len(mes) for mag, mes in zip(magnitudes, measures)}

print(exp(['mag1', 'mag2', 'mag3'], [[1, 2, 3], [3, 4], [5]]))
```